# Is it haram to withhold beneficial advice?

Tags: halal-haram, friendship

I have a friend who messaged me his approach when in an interview process for a certain academic program that accepts multiple students. He is technically competition, and his approach is weak and has flaws/inconsistencies. I can optimize his approach to his application to make him a stronger candidate. Would it be haram to withhold that advice because him and I are technically competing? Although there are multiple spots, there are also multiple candidates.

Any hadith to back this up would be great.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider taking your time to get to know how this site works by taking our [tour] and checking our [help]. Note that advice requests are hardly on topic here, so maybe a better way to ask -to avoid your question being closed by the community as offf-topic- could be asking whether this is halal or haram or what is the of Islam ruling on that...

Comment: The nearest thing i could find so far is this http://www.islamweb.net/emerath/index.php?page=showfatwa&FatwaId=271234 maybe it would be helpful!